# Nodejs Ajax - redirect to the login page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to solve this problem. I use Node Express and jQuery.
The user has been logged out (from another page of the site), but is trying to send an ajax request. How to redirect it to the login page?
I can throw an error like so:

```
if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.json(function() {});
}
```

and after on the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    ...
    error: function() {
        document.location.href = '/logout';
    }
})
```

But can it be done in some other way?
For example, if you do not use Ajax, then I do this:

```
if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Something similar but with Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you use Express, you can call the redirect function on the response:

```js
if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.redirect("/login");
}
```

Comment: The point is that redirect does not work when calling Ajax.

Comment: @DrugojAndrew I don't believe that's possible then, the only solution would be to send back a response to the client to redirect them back to the login page.

Comment: It probably is. I was hoping that a solution could be found.

Comment: I never found a way to do this. Right now I'm just sending a 401 error:
`if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.status(401).send();
}

error: function(response, status, error) {
    if (response.status === 401) window.location = '/logout';
}`